# How can I read classes, IDs or tags styles inside a text file using regular expression?

Tags: c#, css, .net, regex, file-io

I have a problem with regular expression, I need a regular expression to read classes names with properties and the same thing with IDs and Tags styling, each match must have one block; class name (or classes names) with their style!

To explain my problem, the regular expression must match the following syntax of styling:

```
#myId {
    margin: 10px 8px 9px 0;
}

.myClass1 {
    margin: 10px -8px 9px 0;
    padding: 10px 8px 9px 0;
}

-my-tag {
    margin-down     :-10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

-my-tag #my-id{
    margin-down     :-10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#_myI4D6 {margin:10px;}

.myclass.myclass_too {
}
.myclass .myclass_too {                                
    margin-up:10px;
    bac: url "(../../image/p_n-G.png)";
    Margin: 10px 0 10PX 10Px;
    }

#myID .myclass:first-child my-tag {
     margin:     10px;
}

.emptyclass {
}
.classname 
tagnam {
  padding: 40px 999px        ; 
}

.className #myid
{
    maRgin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}
```

the first match must be :

```
#myId {
        margin: 10px 8px 9px 0;
    }
```

On advanced if you can solve the comment problem, maybe class commented like:

```
/* #myId {
        margin: 10px 8px 9px 0;
    } */
```

I don't need to match it.

Note: I write a program using C#, and please note white spaces problems too (Tabs, newlines and spaces).

Comment: What have you tried? What worked? What didn't? ("Write the complete code for me" is considered somewhat rude here)

Comment: Regular expressions are probably not the best tool for the job in this situation. You'd have to be very careful with opening and closing braces. For example, what about this piece of CSS: `p:before { content: '}'; }` ?

Comment: Read this article: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/18/7-principles-of-clean-and-optimized-css-code/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to implement CSS parsing in C#. I can't help you with the regex, but I would strongly suggest you avoid implementing such a thing yourself and use an existing CSS parsing library and save yourself tons of efforts.

Comment: +1 I do totally agree with this sentiment; I just thought I'd answer the question literally and give a regex which matches a rule :)

Comment: Everyone: go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366028/what-is-a-good-c-c-css-parser; and http://joysofprogramming.com/install-libcss-parser-pp0-ubuntu/

Comment: Yes, you say the best, but if you know the best lib that can i download and it to my project, it will be fantastic.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

try this with [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx)

```
Regex.Matches(cssString, @"[^{]+\{[^}]+?}");
```

Each match should be a complete block.

From there you can get the selector from the bit up to the first '{' in each match.

## Warning!

As Samir Talwar commented directly on your question - a regex approach is especially going to struggle with '{' and '}' characters nested within style rules; because Regex can't handle context.

You might want to look instead at a grammar-based solution with [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) (steep learning curve but there is already a [css 2.1 grammar if you search down this page](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list)); or indeed as other people have suggested, a parser specifically crafted towards parsing CSS.