# Drawing Qt controls in paintEvent with respecting style sheets properties

Tags: qt, class, colors, qtstylesheets

Is there a class or method in Qt to get properties like "border-color", "border-style", ...

This may be usefull to create and paint own (derived) controls based on currently selected style sheets.

**Example**:

```
QPushButton {
    border: 3px solid red;
    background: blue;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The code:

```
class QPushButtonCircle : public QPushButton {
};
```

QPushButtonCircle would be a button that is circular. Even the border is circular. The border should 3 pixels width, solid and colored red. The background should be colored blue.

I din't find any way expect drawing entierly in paintEvent and ignoring any style sheets. But there must be a better way.

The best would be something like:

```
QCssStyle cssStyle = widget->...->getCssStyle();

QPen border = cssStyle->border(QCssStyle::Top);
QBrush background = cssStyle->background();
QMargins margins = cssStyle->margins();
QMargins padding = cssStyle->padding();
...
```

This would allow us to draw our own controls like in:

```
QStylePainter p(this);

QRect r = rect();
r.adjust(cssStyle->margins().left(), ...);

p.setPen(cssStyle->border());
p.setBrush(cssStyle->brush());
p.drawEllipse(r);

r.adjust(cssStyle->padding().left(), ...);
p.drawText(r, ...);
```

A better solution would be a method to draw things like with `QStyle::drawControl`, `QStyle::drawPrimitive`... but with respecting a QPainterPath (or simpler primitives) instead of assuming rectangular controls.

What is the best way to create owner drawn controls in Qt with derived colors from style sheets?

Comment: Whoa, that would be a really great thing to have, but there is no. Probably you can implement it as a wrapper over `QString` css property by parsing it with [some parser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/366028/693538). But without touching the Qt internals it is difficult to handle this: *widget's `stylesheet` property is not the complete computed style: parents and qApp also influence*. Probably a reason for feature request to Qt devs...

Answer (score 0):

> I din't find any way expect drawing entierly in paintEvent and ignoring any style sheets. But there must be a better way.

Widgets in Qt are rectangles, and cannot have any other shape. Take a look at the [box model](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-customizing.html). So any other way will be as tricky as the one you are trying to use.

[There is a suggestion](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/1623) using [QGraphicView](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsview.html).

EDIT:

I have never tried myself, but you can try to set a [mask on top of the button](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setMask) with the shape you want, either using a `QBitmap` or a `QRegion`. The other `css` elements (color, etc..)can be set up by updating the stylesheet. This is a much less pain in the *you know what* solution if you can make it work, because you don't need to deal with custom paint events.

Comment: QGraphicsView will entirely ignore the style sheet also. Btw. QDial is also a circular shaped control that ignores the style sheet except something like "background-color" since changing this colors will update the palette of that control. It seems that Qt developers only work with the palette here. Settings the background color was the only property I could changed from style sheet by the way. Others are ignored.

Comment: You did not try the option to mask using a circular region??

Comment: I tested masks some time ago, but this does not solve my problem. The mask only gurantees that certain parts are not drawn (and invisible). In case of a circular buttons this would mean that the entire border is invisible for example. This may be usefull for special designed splash screens, but not for controls.